# Отступы между колонками в flex grid foundation

Tags: html, css, flexbox, foundation

Как в foundation поставить отступы между колонками используя flex grid?

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="columns small-3">1</div>
     <div class="columns small-3">2</div>
     <div class="columns small-3">3</div>
     <div class="columns small-3">4</div>
</div>
```

В файле `settings.scss` есть переменная `$grid-column-gutter` с двумя значениями `small` и `medium`, но как нею пользоватся?

Comment: Отступы выставляются в виде `padding` который равен значению `$grid-column-gutter / 2` для данного разрешения экрана.

Comment: Не работает, показывает ошибку в консоли

Comment: Что не работает, какую ошибку? Здесь телепатов нет.